# How to smooth plot (interpolate) in Matlab using patch function

Tags: matlab, patch

I have this piece of code to generate the below plot:

```matlab
f1 = figure(1);
patch(X,Y,stress_xx,'FaceColor','interp','LineStyle','none');
title('Distribution of stress xx','FontWeight', 'bold');
colormap jet;
axis equal;
```

[image]

How can I smooth the plot so that I won't see the lines in between? FaceColor interp doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: by generating more xy pairs of your data, but you'd need to share that. just use `interp2` to increase the density of you rmesh

Comment: Don’t use `patch`, it’s a low-level graphics function. Use `pcolor` instead. You are getting interpolation, but the colors for each square at one vertex don’t match, because you’re not generating the patches correctly.

Comment: That you like `patch`  perhaps comes from pgfplots, where this is a standard way to go. In MATLAB one of the ideas above

Comment: try typing `shading interp` in Matlab console.